# How to exclude a portfolio category

Tags: php, wordpress, function, portfolio

I have a theme with a portfolio page which allows me to exclude certain portfolio categories, by **unchecking** the categories i would like hide. (e.g Film, Art)

The problem is that certain portfolio items are assigned to multiple categories and my theme wont show the portfolio item if a category is unchecked but still is assigned to a category that is checked (so multiple categories).

How do i go about fixing this? I think i found the code in my functions file but im not certain.

I tried changing the operator from 'NOT IN' to 'IN' but this ends up showing all the cetegories. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    if ( isset( $cat ) && $cat!=-1 ) {
        //include a category
        $query_args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => PEXETO_PORTFOLIO_TAXONOMY,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $cat
            )
        );
    }
    if ( !empty( $excludeCats ) ) {
        if ( !isset( $query_args['tax_query'] ) ) {
            $query_args['tax_query'] = array();
        }
        //exclude categories
        $query_args['tax_query'][]= array(
            'taxonomy' => PEXETO_PORTFOLIO_TAXONOMY,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $excludeCats,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem occurs on the portfolio archive.
If this is the case, as a workaround I would suggest getting all the visible categories and adding them to the tax_query.

```
if( ! empty( $excludeCats ) ) {
    $visibleCats = array_diff( $allCats, $excludeCats );
}
if ( !empty( $excludeCats ) ) {
    if ( !isset( $query_args['tax_query'] ) ) {
        $query_args['tax_query'] = array();
    }
    //exclude categories
    $query_args['tax_query'][]= array(
        'taxonomy' => PEXETO_PORTFOLIO_TAXONOMY,
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $visibleCats,
        'operator' => 'IN'
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey there, Thanks allot for looking into it. Unfortunately, this didn't seem to solve the problem for me. I think the problem lies in the $allCats query since this query doesn't appear anywhere else in my functions file. You wouldn't happen to have any other suggestions? Thanks allot!